# @incollection entries in biblatex mla-new

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I am using

```
\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}
```

with

```
@incollection{test,
author      = "Author Name",
title       = "Article Title",
editor      = "Editor Name",
booktitle   = "Book Title",
publisher   = "Publisher",
address     = "Address",
edition     = "14th edition",
year        = 2012,
pages       = "119-127",
}
```

and receive

> Name, Author. “Article Title.”Book Title. Edited by Editor Name. 14th edition. 
>     Address:Publisher, 2012. 119–127. Print.

As opposed to pudue owls':

> Last name, First name. "Title of Essay." Title of Collection, edited by Editor's Name(s), Publisher, Year, Page range of entry.

How can I change the order of the publisher and other entries on the end, and remove the "Print."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex-mla` version `2016/11/01 v1.9` and a recent version of `biblatex` (I tested with 3.12, but anything fairly recent should be OK) the following MWE

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{test,
author      = "Author Name",
title       = "Article Title",
editor      = "Editor Name",
booktitle   = "Book Title",
publisher   = "Publisher",
address     = "Address",
edition     = "14th edition",
year        = 2012,
pages       = "119-127",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Name, Author. “Article Title.” Book Title, edited by Editor Name, 14th edition, Publisher, 2012, pp. 119–127.]

which looks right according to https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_works_cited_page_books.html.

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the "Print" at the end... I am using overleaf, as well as the MLA13.sty package

Comment: @Phil Overleaf are probably running an outdated version of the package. You could try uploading the necessary newer files from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla but this may or may not work and actually cause more version incompatibilities.

Comment: Well... I uploaded the folder to overleaf, and it completely broke biblatex. Now nothing that I do is cited at all, and it cannot find my .bib file I think. I tried deleting the folder I uploaded, but it is still broken...

Comment: Ok, I started a new project, copy and pasted the .tex and .bib into the new project and I have no idea how, but it works the way it did, and it got rid of the "Print.". HOWEVER, now none of the URLs show up in my online sources...

Comment: @Phil In a short test URLs were printed just fine for `@online` entries. I suggest you ask a new question with a suitable MWE about the issue. If possible include your package versions. You can find out the versions by adding `\listfiles` to the top of the code (as in my MWE), then the `.log` file should contain a list of packages and their versions at the end. (There should be a way to make Overleaf show the entire `.log` to you or to download it and inspect it manually if you click on the button for the log infos.)